# graphics mode error in desktop ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, graphics, shutdown, mode

I have trouble with my Ubuntu desktop 18.04. I wad installing a package and uninstalling a python3-minimal in two terminal at the same time.the battery gone empty and laptop went shutdown and WiFi go to shutdown suddenly too. Now when I turn on my laptop(lenovo-Y5070),I see an (E:the system is on low graphics mode).
I tried to solve this problem by resetting it with using resetter-3 and also with boot menu and installing broken packages too. But non of them was help full.And I can't remove broken packages .Unfortunately I cant install broken packages and their in-dependencies.
What should I do? (my Linux is switched with windows 10.)

Answer (score 0):

done it.I solved my problem.I think the best way to improve my problem is downloading Ubuntu drivers(ISO drivers) and extract them in a USB, After that going to the boot menu and reinstall the Ubuntu from zero. But if I had back up from my last destroyed Ubuntu I could bring back my programs and apps. but I hadn't .Um I downloaded the Ubuntu driver and install Ubuntu 19.04 instead last Ubuntu 18.04.
I hope my suggestion was true and helpful.